# Javascript Checking for empty datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried every permutation of checking for this logic to work and I cannot find the right syntax.

I have the following bit of Javascript:

```
var d = $("#myDatepicker1").datepicker("getDate");
if ($.isEmptyObject(d)) {
    $("#dailySummaryDateSelector").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
}
```

When the page loads and `d` is evaluated Firebug shows it as `Object [ ]`

In the `if` statement I've tried:

```
if (d == null) {
if (d == {}) {
if (d == Object()) {
if ($.isEmptyObject(d)) {
if (d.isEmptyObject()) {
```

None of these work.  As far as I can tell `Object [ ]` is an empty object so how do I actually test for that and get the  contents of the `if` statement to execute?

Comment: Strange. `(d == null)` should work. You do realize you are calling two ids (`$("#myDatepicker1")` and `$("#dailySummaryDateSelector")`), right?

Comment: Well spotted!!  I cannot believe I missed that! (d == null) is indeed working now!

Comment: A datepicker is initialized with the current date as a startdate, so it should'nt normally return null at all, unless you explicitly set it to have no date selected. If the problem is trying to get the date from an object that does'nt exist because you did'nt check your selectors, @acdcjunior should add that as an answer, and you should accept it, as it's well spotted.

Comment: So who's down voting this?

Answer (score 6):

**getDate()**

Returns: Date

> Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has
>   been selected. This method does not accept any arguments.

```
if($("#myDatepicker1").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
  alert("empty");
}
```

Comment: Empty (jQuery) object !== null

Comment: @Juhana not if you're checking for an empty date.

Comment: @Juhana that checks if the element object is null not if the date is null.

Comment: The OP says it returns an empty object, which `.datepicker("getDate")` does if the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that missed it my code was broken!

```
var d = $("#myDatepicker1").datepicker("getDate");
if ($.isEmptyObject(d)) {
    $("#dailySummaryDateSelector").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
}
```

Should have been:

```
var d = $("#dailySummaryDateSelector").datepicker("getDate");
if ($.isEmptyObject(d)) {
    $("#dailySummaryDateSelector").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
}
```

Now this works:

```
var d = $("#dailySummaryDateSelector").datepicker("getDate");
if (d == null) {
    $("#dailySummaryDateSelector").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
}
```